# Using .beget() in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In Javascript Koans, `.beget()` is used to, I suppose, allow a new prototype be created with identical traits? I'm hoping to clarify whether the `Gonzo.prototype = Muppet.prototype.beget();` is what allows `gonzo.answerNanny());` to work, or whether it's the `Muppet.call(this, age, hobby);`

```
function Muppet(age, hobby) {
  this.age = age;
  this.hobby = hobby;

  this.answerNanny = function(){
    return "Everything's cool!";
  }
}

function Gonzo(age, hobby, trick) {
  Muppet.call(this, age, hobby);
  this.trick = trick;

  this.doTrick = function() {
    return this.trick;
  }
}
Gonzo.prototype = Muppet.prototype.beget();

it("should be able to call a method on the base object", function() {
    expect(this.gonzo.answerNanny()).toEqual("Everything's cool!");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this.answerNanny` function is a public priviledge function declared within the `Muppet` constructor. Since it's declared in the constructor and not on the `Muppet.prototype` then it's `Muppet.call(this, age, hobby);` that will add the `answerNanny` member to the `Gonzo` instance.

However, since the `answerNanny` function doesn't have to be priviledged (it doesn't access any variables that are private to the `Muppet` constructor) then it should really be defined on `Muppet.prototype`.

Finally, note that `beget` is not native JavaScript. I'm not sure to which implementation it refers here, but I believe it shall be similar to [the one described by Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html). The same can be achieved using `Gonzo.prototype = Object.create(Muppet.prototype);`

Comment: If that's the case, what's the point of the `Muppet.prototype.beget();` ? Isn't the prototype of Muppet just `Object()'`?

Comment: @komali_2 There's a difference between `Muppet.prototype` and `muppetInstance.__proto__`. `Muppet.prototype` is not the same as an empty object. It has for instance a constructor property that points back to `Muppet`. `Gonzo.prototype = Muppet.prototype.beget()` is correctly setting up the prototype chain here, but the chain is not being relied upon so it's pretty much useless. The only thing is that it enables `gonzoInstance instanceof Muppet` to be true.